# How to write back to database from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql

I use LINQ to SQL to get data from a database and use a service contract to access it in Silverlight at the client side. I display the data in a DataGrid. Now how do I make sure that any changes in the datagrid is written back to the database?

EDIT:

This is the example code I implemented:
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid-cs/

Here I wanted any change in the datagrid reflected back in the database.

The SubmitChanges function works in the DataContext object which is:

```
public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
```

But this is not exposed in the contract and so not visible in the client side code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this command :

_myDomainContext.SubmitChanges();

If your want more information take a look on article :

"How SubmitChanges works in .NET RIA Servies" : http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/08/10/how-submitchanges-works-in-net-ria-servies.aspx

Comment: I am not able to access the domain context in client side. Only the individual objects corresponding to each table is accessible. Should I write methods on server side which uses SubmitChanges and expose it to the client?